# How to use .NET GeoCoordinateWatcher to get only locations from GPS(GNSS) devices?

Tags: .net

I have a Bluetooth connected NMEA device that can output a position every 1 tenth of a second. I also have another USB connected device that can output a position every second.

The issue is that the .NET location service uses all possible means of geotagging, diluting the precision of the GNSS device, outputting positions at random times and/or deceiving the user that it is connected to a GNSS device.

If I go completely offline (no internet, no wifi, no cell reception) and delete location history, it seems to work fine. This is though not a solution for me, as the app will not only be used by me, and it is a huge inconvenience anyway to go through all this, only to achieve something that should be achievable by software means. Moreover, using the app with any other location service than GPS (GNSS) location is useless.

Is there any way that I can use `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher` to get only GPS (GNSS) positions?

Comment: Have you looked at the various accuracy options (both in what you request from the watcher and the reported values when results are returned)?

Comment: There are two accuracy options, the `GeoCoordinateWatcher.DesiredAccuracy`, which has two options, default, and high, and there's a warning that 'high' might use services that costs money. From this I get that it will try to use mobile data, so not helpful. The other accuracy option is under `GeoCoordinateWatcher.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy`, which again does not give any guarantees that it uses the GPS.

Comment: No, it doesn't guarantee GPS. But if your actual underlying concern is *accuracy* of the positional information, rather than the *specific* means (that you know about today) of obtaining accurate information, and if the reported accuracy is "good enough", does that not solve your problem?

Comment: Both accuracy and how fast I get a new position are important for me. I need the most accurate position that I can get every 0.1 seconds, not the most accurate position that I can get when it reaches my desired horizontal accuracy of, let's say, 1 m. If I limit the accuracy, the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` will only report a new position only when it reaches the desired accuracy. But this means that the position that I get now, might be the position that I had 3 seconds ago, which for me might be 200 meters away.